# allow alphanum space alongwith dot special character in validation

Tags: php

```
 ->add('proposer_name', 'custom', [
                    'rule' => array('custom', '/^[a-z0-9 ]*$/i'),
                    'message' => __('Only alphanumeric characters are allowed')
                ])
```

This is the method I am using in server side validation for name. Also I want to write eg. Mr. ABC DEF in name field. But it is not allowing . in field.  How should be my regex please help.  I working in cakephp 3.x.

Comment: What exactly is allowed and what is not? Is `...` (an ellipsis) also a valid name? Or a single space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the dot inside your character class (square brackets `[]`). It has no special meaning inside.

```
 ->add('proposer_name', 'custom', [
                    'rule' => array('custom', '/^[a-z0-9 .]*$/i'),
                    'message' => __('Only alphanumeric characters are allowed')
                ])
```